# Mule Esb Soap Service Proxying gives no such operation exception

Tags: soap, mule, jax-ws, soapui, esb

I have a requirement where I need to proxy an external web service to a different application using mulesoft ESB's soap service. For this, I decided to create a dummy integration application. I have created a soap web service(This is External web service in the actual business case) in eclipse and exposed that web service using Endpoint class. Now I have created a flow in mule using any point studio. In this flow, I need to create another web service which takes soap request and forwards that soap request to the external web service. You may ask why not directly access external soap service. The reason is I need to do some data insertions and manipulations in our application using mule then forward that request to external web service. 
  Both web service and mule application deployed successfully. I'm using SOAP UI to call mule soap service which performs some manipulations then forwards request to external soap service. Now here I'm getting an exception saying no such operation. The exception I'm getting is at Web service consumer message processor in mule flow. I'm pasting my whole project's code i.e., External Soap Service, Mule Flow and exception stack trace in the respective order. Please go through it and help. I'm stuck here for a couple of days.

**External Web Service Code**

```
package org.atc;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;    

import org.atc.model.DgRunHourData;

@WebService 
public interface GetDataWSI {
    public DgRunHourData[] getData(String startDate, String endDate, String properties);

public String sayHi(String input);

    }

package org.atc;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.atc.model.DgRunHourData;
import org.atc.model.EnergyConsumptionInbound;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.atc.GetDataWSI", serviceName = "GetDataWS")
public class GetDataWS implements GetDataWSI {

public DgRunHourData[] getData(String startDate, String endDate, String properties) {

 System.out.println("startDate:" + startDate);
 System.out.println("endDate:" + endDate);
 System.out.println("country" + properties);

  DgRunHourData[] dgRunHourDataList = new DgRunHourData[4];  
  DgRunHourData drhd1 = new DgRunHourData("1", "20", "2015-01-01 00:00:00");
  DgRunHourData drhd2 = new DgRunHourData("2", "20", "2015-01-01 00:00:00");
  DgRunHourData drhd3 = new DgRunHourData("3", "20", "2015-01-01 00:00:00");
  DgRunHourData drhd4 = new DgRunHourData("4", "20", "2015-01-01 00:00:00");

   dgRunHourDataList[0] = drhd1;
   dgRunHourDataList[1] = drhd2;
   dgRunHourDataList[2] = drhd3;
   dgRunHourDataList[3] = drhd4;

   return dgRunHourDataList;

 }

 @Override
 public String sayHi(String input) {
  System.out.println("Webservice sayHi executing for input " + input);
        return "Hello " + input + " ,Welcome to my WS";
  }
 }

package org.atc.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class DgRunHourData {

    public DgRunHourData() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("DgRunHourData [siteId=");
        builder.append(siteId);
        builder.append(", dgRunHours=");
        builder.append(dgRunHours);
        builder.append(", date=");
        builder.append(date);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dgRunHours == null) ? 0 : dgRunHours.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((siteId == null) ? 0 : siteId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DgRunHourData other = (DgRunHourData) obj;
        if (date == null) {
            if (other.date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
            return false;
        if (dgRunHours == null) {
            if (other.dgRunHours != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dgRunHours.equals(other.dgRunHours))
            return false;
        if (siteId == null) {
            if (other.siteId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!siteId.equals(other.siteId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    private String siteId;
    private String dgRunHours;
    private String date;


    public DgRunHourData(String siteId, String dgRunHours, String date) {
        super();
        this.siteId = siteId;
        this.dgRunHours = dgRunHours;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)
    public String getSiteId() {
        return siteId;
    }

    @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)
    public String getDgRunHours() {
        return dgRunHours;
    }
    @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}

 package org.atc;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Publisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8686/GetDataWSService", new GetDataWS());

    }

}
```

**Mule Flow xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        host="localhost" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <flow name="ProxyWSFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
            path="/api/soap/dummy" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <set-variable variableName="requestTime" value="#[server.dateTime]"
            doc:name="RequestTime" />
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.atc.GetDataWSI"
            doc:name="Proxy Service" />
        <logger
            message="#[payload.startDate]  #[payload.endDate]  #[payload.properties] "
            level="INFO" doc:name="Logger1" />
        <set-variable variableName="methodName"
            value="#[flowVars.cxf_operation.localPart]" doc:name="Variable" />
        <logger message="#[flowVars.methodName]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger2" />
        <set-variable variableName="startDate" value="#[ payload.startDate]" doc:name="set startDate"/>
        <set-variable variableName="endDate" value="#[ payload.endDate]" doc:name="set endDate"/>
        <set-variable variableName="properties" value="#[ payload.properties]" doc:name="set Properties"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="36c48128-823f-4360-835b-97bdaf3f798d" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-variable mimeType="application/java" variableName="endDate"/>
            <dw:input-variable mimeType="application/java" variableName="properties"/>
            <dw:input-variable mimeType="application/java" variableName="startDate"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    ns0#getData: {
        arg0: flowVars.startDate,
        arg1: flowVars.endDate,
        arg2: flowVars.properties
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getData" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[Mule flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSJRZ.png)

**Exception stack trace**

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: getData
INFO  2017-05-08 15:17:30,862 [[ProxyWS].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] com.mulesoft.weave.mule.utils.MuleWeaveFactory$: MimeType was not resolved '*/*' delegating to Java.
ERROR 2017-05-08 15:17:34,444 [[ProxyWS].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
Message               : No such operation: getData. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.
Payload               : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<ns0:getData xmlns:ns0="http://atc.org/">
  <arg0 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
  <arg1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
  <arg2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns0:getData>
Element               : null @ ProxyWS:null:null
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.Exception: No such operation: getData
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:335)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:428)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:237)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:131)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:186)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:494)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:100)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:96)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:60)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:95)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleJAXWSInvoker.invoke(MuleJAXWSInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendThroughCxf(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:422)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:296)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:161)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:49)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:232)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:73)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:72)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:187)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:93)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:49)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:112)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:39)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:133)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Also there is a warning in exception stack trace**

```
WARN  2017-05-08 15:17:34,448 [[ProxyWS].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {atc.org}GetDataWSIService#{atc.org}getData has thrown exception, unwinding now
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation: getData. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:125) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleJAXWSInvoker.invoke(MuleJAXWSInvoker.java:43) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) ~[cxf-api-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
```

Comment: May be you need to check the wsdl if there is such operation present or not? Alternatively, check with your team or service provider (if third party application).

Comment: As said in the beginning, this is not the actual business application. Here I'm just creating dummy application according to the actual business scenario. That WSDL is deployed on my local eclipse environment. And yes, that operation exists. You can check the web service interface and implementation part in the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you used the [Building Web Services with CXF](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/building-web-services-with-cxf) mule documentation as an example.  One thing I noticed is that you define the interface in your Mule flow with `<cxf:simple-service>`, but you do not define the implementation with `<component>`.

See line 13 in the example in the **Configuring the Service** section: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/building-web-services-with-cxf#configuring-the-service

If you are you using Mule 3.8 or later, then you should be using the SOAP APIKit to do all this.  It will make your life *much* easier.

- [Main Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/)
- [Tutorial](https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/apikit-for-soap)